# How to calculate mean of function in a gaussian fit?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, gaussian

I'm using the curve fitting app in MATLAB. If I understand correctly the "b1" component in the left box is the mean of function i.e. the `x` point where `y=50%` and my `x` data is `[-0.8 -0.7 -0.5 0 0.3 0.5 0.7]`, so why is this number in this example so big (631)?

General model Gauss1:

```
f(x) =  a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2)
```

Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):

```
   a1 =  3.862e+258  (-Inf, Inf)

   b1 =       631.2  (-1.117e+06, 1.119e+06)

   c1 =       25.83  (-2.287e+04, 2.292e+04)
```

Comment: write the y data too

Comment: y= [0.2 0 0.2 0.2 0.5 1 1] by looking at the plot that the app gives me I can see the 50% point is somewhere between 0.4 and 0.6 . I don't know how to calculate that number from formula though.

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks like cdf and not pdf. You can use this code for your solution

```
xi=[-0.8,-0.7,-0.5, 0.0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7];
yi= [0.2, 0.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0];
fun=@(v) normcdf(xi,v(1),v(2))-yi;
[v]=lsqnonlin(fun,[1,1]); %[1,2] 
mu=v(1); sigma=v(2);
x=linspace(-1.5,1.5,100);
y=normcdf(x,mu,sigma);
figure(1);clf;plot(xi,yi,'x',x,y);
annotation('textbox',[0.2,0.7,0.1,0.1], 'String',sprintf('mu=%f\nsigma=%f',mu,sigma),'FitBoxToText','on','FontSize',16);
```

you will get: mu=0.24537, sigma=0.213

And if you still want to fit to pdf, just change the function 'normcdf' in 'fun' (and 'y')  to 'normpdf'.